# How can I use arrays with object properties in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

Is there a way to use arrays with object properties without using `@ts-ignore` in typescript

Lets say I have this function, it attempts to convert an array to an array with the prop property. This works fine except for the fact that their is a @ts-ignore

```js
    const addPropToArray = <T extends unknown>(x: T[]): T[] & {prop: number} => {
      //@ts-ignore
      const y: T[] & {prop: number} = [...x];
      y.prop = 3;
      return y
    };
```

Obviously I can't do this

```js
const x: string[] & {prop:number} = // what could go here
```

by itself which is why I was thinking of using the function but even then the function must have a `@ts-ignore`.

Are arrays with object properties just such a bad idea that typescript doesn't try to support them well, or is their something I'm missing?

Maybe their is some variation of this that could work?

```js
const x: string[] & {prop:number} = {...["a","b","c"], prop: 4}
```

obviously the problem here is that it isn't an array any more.

EDIT:
I realize I could just cast the value instead of using `@ts-ignore` but that sill doesn't seem like the best solution

Comment: "Are arrays with object properties just such a bad idea.." ^_^ (If keeping that arrays are distinct from array-like objects with additional object properties..)

Comment: I would probably use `Object.assign` or a spread to get a one-liner

Comment: @jcalz could you answer my question with a demonstration of what you mean?

Comment: I can, when I next get to a non-phone device.

Comment: Oh `Object.assign` will work but a spread will not, by the way.  It would look like `Object.assign([...x], {prop: 3})` but I can’t check that for accuracy at the moment

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkjppm).  Still don't have time yet to write up an answer, but that works at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Object.assign(target, source)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies the enumerable own properties from a `source` object onto the `target` object and returns the augmented `target`.  And the TypeScript [standard library typings for this method](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cec2fda9a53620dc545a2c4d7b0156446ab145b4/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L286) looks like:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
}
```

Meaning that it models the operation as producing the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the types of `source` and the original `target`, which is exactly what you're looking for!

So you can write `addPropToArray()` like this:

```
const addPropToArray = <T extends unknown>(x: T[]): T[] & { prop: number } => {
  return Object.assign([...x], { prop: 3 });
};
```

without [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or [`//@ts-ignore` comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments).

Note that if you ever *do* have to choose between type assertions and `//@ts-ignore`, **choose type assertions**.  They both have the ability to stop errors, and neither is safe.  But type assertions are limited in scope and telling the compiler to treat a certain value as if it were a certain type, while `//@ts-ignore` is merely suppressing the error message and can have strange nonlocal side effects.  Using a type assertion is like  pushing the "temporary hush" button on your smoke detector so you can cook dinner in peace,  while using `//@ts-ignore` is like removing the smoke detector's battery completely.

---

Anyway, let's make sure it works:

```
const z = addPropToArray(["a", "b"]);
console.log(z) // ["a", "b"]
console.log(z.prop) // 3
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQBQE4gA4BUQEFWpwCeMAvDADxYwCmAHlDWAhDAK5gDWYIA7mAD4AFHQBcMLAG0AugEpxU6TABkMAN4wM6DOLBsAtgCMaqGAF8yA9QFgAUDBioaUNqjAwA8oYBWNYFAA6OAgIAEsAczAhSQDYumkAGnVNbXEAZnNZAG47MxzbO1BIWAAvMngkNEwcfEIiaIAiOAakhsMGuXyiiBAAGxoA3pBwoRLZGAB6CZhJJpaYNo7C8B7+weHRgK1McamYNKA)

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously I can't do this `const x: string[] & {prop:number} = // what could go here`

You could do this, if you assign the returned value of a self-executing anonymous function. Something like this, for example:

```
interface ArrayProps {
    prop: number;
}

const x: string[] & ArrayProps = (() => {
    const xPartial: string[] & Partial<ArrayProps> = [];
    xPartial.prop = 3;

    return xPartial as string[] & ArrayProps;
})();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngBSgewAcBnZAbwFgAoASEIMIC5kQBXAWwCNoBuagX2rUE+EMTDIAHs3FRQAcwDaAXWQAyNBmx4ipALzIAFIYCUyPQD5y1GiLETJOOFDDA4AGxlg5IJao1OLm7uADzomLgMxFYGKny0js6uHgB09ETmyADM8TZQEGCsUCBSgcnuyHCksgoq6poROiTx-Cam8UA)

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this without a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), though. Adding a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) instead of the type assertion would require accounting for the path where the type guard fails, so `x` would end up also being able to be `undefined` or something depending on how that path is handled.